# How can I create a Jekyll variable from another in _config.yml?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to create a variable for the image path in _config.yml. I have defined baseurl and want a new one called urlimg: 'baseurl+'images/' Is that syntax correct?

```
urlimg: baseurl.'/images/'
```

Comment: Would this work? ```urlimg: {{baseurl}}'/images/'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to create two variables in your config.yml, like this:

```
url: https://www.example.com/
baseurl: site/
imageurl: images/
```

And use them in your template, like this:

```
{{ imageurl | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}
```